# How to remove extra parentheses in prettier

Tags: vue.js, eslint, prettier

I use .prettierrc with settings:

```
{
  "semi": false,
  "tabWidth": 2,
  "singleQuote": true,
  "bracketSpacing": true,
  "printWidth": 100,
  "trailingComma": "none",
  "arrowParens": "avoid",
  "bracketSameLine": false
}
```

And he puts extra brackets like this in my Vue file:

```
@updateQuery="val => (query = val)"
```

But I need in:

```
@updateQuery="val => query = val"
```

What to do?

Answer (score 0):

In an arrow function if you are making an assignment prettier will fix it like so:

`val => (query = val)`
There's nothing wrong with it.

You can find more info here https://github.com/prettier/prettier/pull/1326